# Show URL from list in iframe below document set

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, document-set

my question is pretty similar to [Can the "Script Editor" webpart retrieve values from a list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108518/can-the-script-editor-webpart-retrieve-values-from-a-list) . But I can not adopt the solution or rather understand it (Sorry, I am not a programmer)

Background:

I have a document library in Sharepoint. Each document set represents a running project in my team.
When a new project (=document set) is created a workflow starts and automatically creates a new empty task list.

```
Document set: https://linktomysharepoint/.../projects/doc-library/Project-test123
Task list: https://linktomysharepoint/.../projects/Lists/Project-test123
```

This works fine. The URL of the task list is also written to a field of the document set.

Problem:

When I open one document set in the library I would like to see the corresponding task list directly below the document set.

Idea:

I want to use the script editor below the document set to show an iframe

```
<iframe src="https://linktomysharepoint/.../projects/Lists/Project-test123"></iframe>
```

But with dynamically content, so e.g.

```
<iframe src="{URL from field}"></iframe>
```

Someone can help me?

Cheers

PS: I don't want to create a new site, which shows document set and task liste separately. I want the task list directly below the document set.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,you could use rest api get URL from field.

Official document:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#working-with-list-items-by-using-rest

Secondly,you could use js/jQuery set the iframe src property.

```
$("iframe ").attr("src", "url from field");
```